# validate array mongoid and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mongoid

I have in model **Invitation** a field and attribute like:

```
field :recipients, :type => Array
```

I have an array with 4 emails in my controller like:

```
@invitation.recipients = ['', '', '', '']
```

I want validate in my model that each array's value match with a email regex sth like:

```
validates_format_of :recipients, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/u, :message => "is not a valid email address"
```

How can I validate regex of an array in mongoid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
RE = /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/u
validate :recipients_format
def recipients_format
  unless recipients.all? { |r| r =~ RE }
    errors[:recipients] = "are not all valid email addresses"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @clyfe, This code goes in controller or in Model? its possible add a method with this code before_save callback? Thank you

Comment: It goes in the model. Not sure what you mean on second phrase.